# Given two numbers, return an array of length num1 with each value nu

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm learning how to code and I'm stuck in this exercise: Given two numbers, return an array of length num1 with each value num2. Print "Jinx!" if they are the same.

Here is the code I have right now:

```
function thisLengthThatValue(num1,num2) {

    if (num1 == num2) {
        console.log("Jinx!");
    }

    var newArray = [];
    var len = 0;

    while (len <= num1) {
        newArray.push(num2);
        len++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working. Could someone please help?

Comment: What is your input and expected output?

Comment: What do you mean with "it is not working"? Does the array happen to contain one additional element? Or does the function not return a value because there is no `return` statement?

Comment: And by the way, you can simply create the array with `Array(num1).fill(num2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check with smaller than smaller or equal, because you start at zero and not at one for the loop.

```
len < num1
```

Then you need to exit the function with returning the wanted string if the values

```
num1 === num2
```

are equal.

```js
function thisLengthThatValue(num1, num2) {

    if (num1 === num2) {      // taken an identity check ===
        return "Jinx!"        // exit function with the value
    }

    var newArray = [];
    var len = 0;

    while (len < num1) {
        newArray.push(num2);
        len++;
    }
    return newArray;
}

console.log(thisLengthThatValue(3, 3));
console.log(thisLengthThatValue(1, 3));
console.log(thisLengthThatValue(3, 1));
```

Comment: @idmean, i think the op is learning to fill an array by iterating. the array methods are the next step after understanding some basic function, like comparing, returning and the use of upper and lower border.

Comment: True enough. In my opinion though, it’s still important mentioning such APIs because otherwise people move on, never knowing about these techniques and write basic code like this over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the `newArray` from the function which you are missing.

```js
function thisLengthThatValue(num1,num2) {
  if (num1 == num2) {
    return "Jinx!";
  }
  var newArray = [];
  var len = 0;
  while (len < num1) {
    newArray.push(num2);
    len++;
  }
  return newArray;
}

var res = thisLengthThatValue(5,2);
console.log(res);
res = thisLengthThatValue(5,5);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function thisLengthThatValue(num1,num2) {

    if (num1 == num2) {
        console.log("Jinx!");
    }

    var newArray = [];
    var len = 0;

    while (len < num1) { // strict inequality
        newArray.push(num2);
        len++;
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

You were checking if array length is lower or **equal** to the desired length and if true, adding a new element.